# Comparar atributos de un objeto que está en un arreglo

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

tengo un inconveniente. Quiero saber como comparar los atributos de un objeto, el cual se encuentra en un arreglo. Para entender mejor a que me refiero, propongo este ejemplo: se tiene una clase Persona, el cual tiene atributos como nombre, edad, sexo e identificación. Se cuenta con otra clase llamada arreglo donde se va a tener a persona como tipo de dato. En el código(Private Persona Lista[];).
Donde se van a almacenar los datos ingresados por el usuario a registrar.
  En el Jframe se creará el diseño correspondiente, donde se quiere ingresar a otra ventana de tal manera que solo pasa al otro Jframe si la identificación está guardada en el vector de objetos. Este es a lo que me refiero ¿como le hago para comparar ese dato en sí con el dato ingresado por el usuario? Saludos a todos espero me puedan orientar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer en primer lugar, es recorrer los elementos de tu **Lista**, y con un metodo getAtributo() tomar el atributo de la persona que te intereza (Se especifican en la clase **Persona**), y al mismo tiempo, lo comparas con la **variable** que almacena el dato ingresado por el **usuario** usando el metodo **equals(Object)**.
Por ejemplo:

```
public class Arreglo{
    private String datoIngresadoPorUsuario;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Persona p : Lista) {
            if (p.getNombre.equals(datoIngresadoPorusuario)) {
                //Si da true es porque son iguales
            }
        }
    }
}
```